AWS ECS auto scale up causing temporary ALB 504 timeouts
we have a service which is a ECS + EC2 setup. With the ECS, we configured service auto scaling. We noticed when auto scaling policy trying to scale up more tasks, we sometimes see transient 504 Gateway timeouts from ALB.
Somethings I've checked:

This happens when new instance is just registered in ALB, and only lasts for 1-2 min.
Sometime, the instance show healthy in ALB, and task show running and healthy in ECS. Sometime, the instance can be temporarily unhealthy but later become healthy again. As AWS doc indicate, ALB will only send traffic if it's healthy.
Not all requests went timeout, only a very small portion (< 1%).
The max target response time did not exceed (or close to) the IDLE timeout (180 seconds). There is no TargetConnectionErrorCount at the time.

Below is one example ALB access log seems indicating some issue between ALB and target connection? (Since the request_processing_time is -1).
type: https
time: 2024-07-25T22:12:31.373696Z
elb: app/xxxx/b3e537e604573ca5
client:port: 52.26.185.88:13328
target:port: 10.0.228.223:8443
request_processing_time: -1
target_processing_time: -1
response_processing_time: -1
elb_status_code: 504
target_status_code: -
received_bytes: 2324
sent_bytes: 292
request: "POST https://xxxxx:443/ HTTP/1.1"
user_agent: "xxxxx"
ssl_cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ssl_protocol: TLSv1.2
target_group_arn: xxxxxxxx
trace_id: "Root=1-xxxxx-xxxxxxx"
domain_name: "xxxxxx"
chosen_cert_arn: "session-reused"
matched_rule_priority: 0
request_creation_time: 2024-07-25T22:12:21.374000Z
actions_executed: "waf,forward"
redirect_url: "-"
error_reason: "-"
target:port_list: "10.0.228.223:8443"
target_status_code_list: "-"
classification: "-"
classification_reason: "-"
conn_trace_id: xxxxxx

Metric of 504 and runningTaskCount:

My guess is that the new registered hosts might not be truly healthy but ALB somehow still send the traffic to it, but I'm not sure how I can check. Wondering if anyone know what could be the cause and how can I solve the issue?
Thanks a lot!

It sounds like you may need to slowly give traffic to new instances of your ECS service, in order give your app time to fully start up or something. You can manage that with the slow_start.duration_seconds setting on your load balancer's target group. Documented here

The time period, in seconds, during which the load balancer sends a newly registered target a linearly increasing share of the traffic to the target group. The range is 30–900 seconds (15 minutes). The default is 0 seconds (disabled).


I tried with slow start, and it do seems reduce the number of 504s. Thanks for the help!
